# Setting Time.zone via application controller and a custom rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, rake

In my `User` model, I have a method to display the time:

```
def display_time
    puts "Time is: #{Time.zone.now}"
end
```

I am setting `Time.zone` for each user in a before filter in the application controller, and then calling the `display_time` method:

```
def my_before_filter
    Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
    current_user.display_time
end
```

I am also setting `Time.zone` for each user in a loop in my rake task (an hourly cron job), and then calling the same method:

```
Users.all.each do |user|
    Time.zone = user.time_zone
    user.display_time
end
```

How can I ensure that the two time zone settings will not interfere with each other ?

I want the `display_time` method to always use the `Time.zone` set via the application controller, except when it is called from the cron task's loop. How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make display_time take the time parameter.

```
def my_before_filter
  Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
  current_user.display_time(Time.zone.now)
end

# app/models/user.rb
def display_time(current_time)
  puts "Time is: #{current_time}"
end
```

From your rake task, send the `current_time` that you want.